# Fazer download de um arquivo em C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, pdf

Boa Tarde, sou iniciante em C# e já procurei essa resposta aqui na internet e não achei de jeito nenhum, estou trabalhando com C# e windows forms, eu tenho uma pasta dentro da minha aplicação chamada img e tenho um arquivo pdf dentro dela, gostaria que quando o cliente clicasse no botão ele fizesse o download desse arquivo pdf para a pasta downloads do computador do cliente. Como eu posso fazer isso? pois já tentei de tudo e não consigo.

```
  //Baixar Pdf
        private void toolStripButton11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                this.DownloadFile("img\\Ajuda.pdf", "Ajuda.pdf");
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade você não precisa fazer `download`, você precisa copiar o arquivo para a pasta `Downloads`. Este código irá ajudá-lo:

```
    string finalPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "Downloads\\Ajuda.pdf");
    System.IO.File.Copy("img\\Ajuda.pdf", finalPath);
```

Métodos usados:
[File.Copy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=net-5.0)
[Path.Combine](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0)
[Environment.GetFolderPath](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=net-5.0)

Comment: mto obrigado, essa solução já resolve meu problema.

Comment: vc saberia me dizer como eu faço pra verificar se o arquivo já existe na pasta de downloads?

Comment: @Joana Use o File.Exists https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.exists?view=net-5.0

Comment: Utilizei conforme o codigo mostra, mas como a minha pasta é "Donwloads" e não tem o C: na frente ele não reconhece a pasta...

Comment: @Joana ajuste finalPath conforme a necessidade. Veja: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878605/Getting-all-Special-Folders-in-NET

Comment: valew consegui agora com esta ultima dica, mto obrigado msm :)

Answer (score 0):

Achei um código no Stack Overflow (inglês) para o que você deseja fazer. É um pouco diferente, mas é para a mesma necessidade.

```cs
    protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtName.Text)) return;            
       Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
       Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + txtName.Text);
       string filePath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/SavedFolder/PDF", txtName.Text));
       Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
       Response.End();
    }
```

> **Fonte:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402035/how-to-download-pdf-file-from-files-on-button-click

Comment: mto obrigado pela atenção, eu tentei utilizar a resposta acima, mas fica aparecendo que "Response não existe no contexto atual" e que "Server não existe no contexto atual", e nem aparece nenhuma sugestão de assembly .

Comment: Este artigo pode ajudar neste problema https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56018968/the-name-response-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

Comment: obrigado por tentar me ajudar, mas a solução do isaque funcionou pra mim, mto obrigado.